# Validation fires before button click in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, model-validation

I am new in MVC3. please ignore in case if ask anything not up to the mark.

I have partial view name "_LikeFilter". this view has textbox in it.

Here is LikeFilterModel.

```
public class LikeFilterModel
{
  [Required]
  public string SearchText { get; set; }
}
```

_LikeFilter View

```
@model PMEX.CSR.Models.LikeFilterModel
@{
Layout = null;
 }
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">   </script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div align="center">
<div class="editor-label">
    @{
        Html.LabelFor(m => m.ReportName);
    }
    <div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Search By Name :
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchText, new { @class = "editor-field" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SearchText)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
  </div>
```

Here is my Reports View calling _LikeFilter Partail view.

```
@{
  using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

    <div align="center">
           <div>

                @{
        // calling partial view
        Html.RenderAction("GetCommodityReportFilter", "LikeFilter"); 

                }
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Display" />
            </div>

    </div>     
    }
  }
```

LikeFilterController class

```
 Public class LikeFilterController 
 {
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetCommodityReportFilter(LikeFilterModel modelObj)
    {
        LikeFilterModel model = null;
        if (Request.HttpMethod != "POST")
        {
            model = new LikeFilterModel();
            model.ReportName = ReportType.Commodity;
        }
        else
            model = modelObj;

        return GetLikeFilter(model);
    }




 private ActionResult GetLikeFilter(LikeFilterModel modelObj)
    {
        LikeFilterModel model = modelObj;
        model.ReportName = modelObj.ReportName;
        model.ReportStatuses = GetStatuses();
        ViewBag.LikeFilterAttributes = model;
        return View("_LikeFilter", model);
    }

   }
```

problem when my page appears it show me the error Message "SearchText is required"

i want this validation after some input in the textbox or on button click. Not when page appears first time.

[image]

Comment: What's the `_LikeFilter` view look like?

Comment: @lc.please now see me edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the model binding that causes the validation to fire.
You need to clear the model state.

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetCommodityReportFilter(LikeFilterModel modelObj)
    {
        LikeFilterModel model = null;
        if (Request.HttpMethod != "POST")
        {
            ModelState.Clear(); // add this
            model = new LikeFilterModel();
            model.ReportName = ReportType.Commodity;
        }
        else
            model = modelObj;

        return GetLikeFilter(model);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks its done. but it would be very great if you could tell me the reason behind to clear the modelstate ?

Comment: When you pass LikeFilterModel modelObj as argument to the action method it is model binded which triggers validation. You need to clear the Model state in "GET" but not for "POST".